# ClojureDart: Execution error at cljd.compiler/load-libs-info (compiler.cljc:126). EOF while reading

Tags: flutter, dart, clojure

While translating a flutter cookbook into ClojureDart, I encoutered this error.
I initialized the project that way:

```sh
$ mkdir -p src/samples && touch src/samples/tabs.cljd
$ clj -M -m cljd.build init --dart samples.tabs
```

And then I compiled it this way:

```sh
$ clj -M -m cljd.build flutter
```

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My `.clojuredart/libs-info.edn` file was empty, that is why it causes EOF.
The mistake here is not from the code itself, but from the way I initialized the project.
Instead of doing:

```sh
$ clj -M -m cljd.build init --dart samples.tabs
```

I should have just done:

```sh
$ clj -M -m cljd.build init samples.tabs
```

without the `--dart`.

There are two ways to correct this.

1. Start again with the correct command
2. redirect the output of the analyzer into libs-info.edn.
   If you run `ls` into `.clojuredart`, you will notice that there are two files: `analyzer.dart` and `libs-info.edn`. ClojureDart uses the analyzer to product dart code.
   run:

```sh
$ dart .clojuredart/analyzer.dart > .clojuredart/libs-info.edn
```

And it should works, just like it did for me !